# raspberry pi port forwading troubles

Tags: raspberry-pi, port-forwarding

I use my raspberry pi as a media server to access music, pictures, videos etc. I have smb set up and it works great. I'm now trying to make it so i can access my files outside of my network. I tried following this guide https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56149 and am having difficulty.

so far I have done the following steps

```
 sudo apt-get install vsftpd
 sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Then added the following configs

```
 ##Edit or uncomment the following lines ::::
 Anonymous_enable=NO
 Local_enable=YES
 Write_enable=YES
 Ascii_upload_enable=YES
 Ascii_download_enable=YES

 ##ADD the following lines to the bottom of the file!
 pasv_enable=YES
 listen_port=64000
 pasv_min_port=64001
 pasv_max_port=64040
 pasv_address= [my routers ip address]
 pasv_address_resolve=YES
 local_root=/mnt/usbstorage/Media
```

Then restarted

```
 sudo service vsftpd restart
```

the directions then say

important! Now go into your Router settings and forward port 64000 to 64040, to the local IP of your raspberry.

I then tried port forwarding (been trying for hours) with no luck..

This is what my router settings look like. I'm just not sure what numbers to put where. [image]

for local ip I used my raspi's static ip; 
Everything else I'm totally clueless. I've tried all types of combinations and no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm not sure if it matters at all by my raspberry pi is connected to my router via ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Enable Port Forwarding Yes
Port Range 64000-64040
Local IP (raspi IP)
```

It matters a lot if your RPi is connected or not.  ;-)